# Converting an ASTNode into code

Tags: eclipse-jdt

How does one convert an [ASTNode](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTNode.html) (or at least a [CompilationUnit](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FCompilationUnit.html)) into a valid piece of source code?

The documentation says that one shouldn't use `toString`, but doesn't mention any alternatives:

> Returns a string representation of this node suitable for debugging purposes only.

CompilationUnits have [`rewrite`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FCompilationUnit.html), but that one does not work for ASTs created by hand.

Formatting options would be nice to have, but I'd basically be satisfied with anything that turns arbitrary ASTNodes into semantically equivalent source code.

Answer (score 1):

In JDT the normal way for AST manipulation is to start with a basic `CompilationUnit` and then use a rewriter to add content. Then `ASTRewriteAnalyzer` / `ASTRewriteFormatter` should take care of creating formatted source code. Creating a CU just containing a stub type declaration shouldn't be hard, so that's one option.

If that doesn't suite your needs, you may want to experiement with directly calling the internal `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewriteFlattener.asString(ASTNode, RewriteEventStore)`. If not editing existing files, you may probably ignore the events collected in the `RewriteEventStore`, just use the returned String.